# How to stop variables becoming local?

Tags: python, variables, global-variables, local-variables

I'm trying to create a function to verify if a move in a game is legal. At the top of my code, I declared the variable Valid.

```
p1 = [1,1]
p2 = [1,1]
turn = 1
move = 0
Valid = False
```

and later on, I call the function `check_swap()` and right now, I am just returning that it is `True` (I will implement the checking later on):

```
if move == 2:
    print("Swaping selected")
    print("you have " + str(p1[0] + p1[1]) + " in total.")
    want_p1_hand_1 = input("How many do you want hand 1 to have?")
    want_p1_hand_2 = input("How many do you want hand 2 to have?")

    check_swap(p1, p2, turn, want_p1_hand_1, want_p1_hand_2)
    if Valid == True:
        p1[0] = want_p1_hand_1
        p1[1] = want_p1_hand_2
        print_game(p1, p2)
    else:
        print("That didn't work")


def check_swap(p1, p2, turn, want_p1_hand_1, want_p1_hand_2):
    Valid = True
    return Valid
```

Then, it defaults to the `else` statement and prints `"That didn't work"`.
At first I just had `Valid = True`, and it said that `Valid` was called but never used, even though it is. I searched Stackoverflow and adding the `return Valid` seemed like the right thing to do,  but it didn't work.

Comment: Unrelated, but you may want to check out [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Valid = True` in `check_swap` actually just creates a new local variable, separate from the global `Valid`.

Now, you could use the global statement, but a better way to write the code would be to assign the return value of `check_swap` to `Valid`.

```py
Valid = check_swap(p1, p2, turn, want_p1_hand_1, want_p1_hand_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign to global variables you'll need the `global` keyword. Here's an example ran in the Python REPL:

```py
>>> valid = False
>>> 
>>> def not_using_global():
...     valid = True
...     print(valid)
...
>>> def using_global():
...     global valid
...     valid = True
...     print(valid)
...
>>>
>>> not_using_global()
True
>>> print (valid)
False
>>>
>>> using_global()
True
>>> print(valid)
True
```